# How to target CSS form labels/values?

Tags: css, forms, label

I'm trying to mimic the placeholder attribute in my login/password form, using pure CSS.

Is there a way to do this? Can I absolutely positioning my label or values which say "user/password" to make them look like they are placeholder text in the field?

Not sure how to target the label/value.

```
<form>

<input type="text" id="username" label="username">

<input type="password" id="password" label="password">

</form>
```

Thanks all.

Comment: You cannot do this with pure CSS - you would need JavaScript

Comment: There has to be a way w/ hover's positioning, display...etc to do this with CSS.  Bottom line, it's probably overkill when you could just do it with javascript, but...

Answer (score 2):

I would use the new `placeholder` css3 property and let old browsers be old browsers.

http://jsfiddle.net/fmr3J/

```
<input type="text" id="username" label="username" placeholder="username">
<input type="password" id="password" label="password" placeholder="password">
```

Comment: Thanks but I have to make it compatible with IE 7+.

Comment: You will need to use javascript then. This site has a walkthrough on how to accomplis this. http://www.cssnewbie.com/cross-browser-support-for-html5-placeholder-text-in-forms/